# how do you manage servers' root passwords

Tags: linux, security, passwords, ssh-keys

In our administration team everyone has root passwords for all client servers.
But what should we do if one of the team members is not longer working with us?
He still has our passwords and we have to change them all, every time someone leave us.

Now we are using ssh keys instead of passwords, but this is not helpful if we have to use something other than ssh.

Answer (score 23):

The systems I run have a [sudo](http://www.sudo.ws/)-only policy. i.e., the root password is `*` (disabled), and people have to use sudo to get root access. You can then edit your `sudoers` file to grant/revoke people's access. It's very granular, and has lots of configurability---but has sensible defaults, so it won't take you long to set up.

Comment: How often do you check for other uid/gid 0 users and for the root password still being disabled?

Comment: On good operating systems (e.g., OpenBSD), there is a daily email telling you what changes have been made to various important files, such as the password database (as well as the auditing script itself). :-)

Comment: That auditing script also alerts you to any new setuid programs, by the way.

Comment: And of course such auditing programs also exist for linux. :)

Comment: Always using sudo is handy because everything is logged. Unfortunately it's a bit awkward for things like redirection, or for browsing directories that aren't world readable so we often resort to "sudo sh" or similar, which unfortunately means you don't get everything logged.

Comment: But what if you must go to single user mode? Most Linux distros I know will ask for the _real_ root PW.

Comment: You can generate a random long password, write it on a piece of paper, and lock it somewhere to use for there purposes.

Comment: sleske: last I checked if root password is * you will get a # prompt without a password on Linux.

Comment: @Joshua: On distros designed for disabled-root, like Ubuntu and Debian, this is true. I don't believe this is true in general, so distros that don't support it, you'd have to patch your `sulogin` with the Ubuntu patches first.

Comment: With slackware it was also true as single user mode script spawned a root shell without sulogin.

Answer (score 6):

I would normally suggest the following:

1. Use a *blank* root password.
2. Disable telnet
3. Set ssh for no-root-login (or root login by public key only)
4. Disable su to root by adding this to the top of /etc/suauth: 'root:ALL:DENY'
5. Enable secure tty for root login on console only (tty1-tty8)
6. Use sudo for normal root access

Now then, with this setting, all users must use sudo for remote admin,
but when the system is seriously messed up, there is no hunting for
the root password to unlock the console.

EDIT: other system administration tools that provide their own logins will also need adjusting.

Comment: That's a really nice setup. I like the idea of pw-less login at the physical console. However, you must make sure that any software that uses system accounts for authentication (WebMin etc.) are also adapted.

Comment: Thank you, and thank you for pointing out that other software sometimes allows login via unexpected paths.

Answer (score 4):

While it is a good idea to use a sudo only policy like Chris suggested depending on the the size of your system an ldap approach may also be helpful. We complement that by a file that contains all the root passwords but the root passwords are really long and unmemorable. While  that may be considered a security flaw it allows us to still log in if the ldap server is down.

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but I remember that sudoers can be stored in LDAP too, which is super-cool when you have tons of servers that are to be centrally managed. :-) +1

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the sudo policy, which is probably better, there is no reason why each admin couldn't have their own account with UID 0, but named differently, with a different password and even different home directory.  Just remove their account when they're gone.

Answer (score 1):

We just made it really easy to change the root passwords on every machine we admininster so when people left we just ran the script. I know not very savvy but it worked. Before my time, everyone in the company had access to root on all server. luckily we moved away from that.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, if someone leaves our team, we don't bother changing root passwords.  Either they left the company (and have no way to access the machines anymore as their VPN has been revoked, as has their badge access to the building, and their wireless access to the network), or they're in another department inside the company and have the professionalism to not screw with our environment.

Is it a security hole?  Maybe.  But, really, if they wanted to screw with our environment, they would have done so prior to moving on.

So far, anyone leaving the team who wants to gain access to our machines again has always asked permission, even though they could get on without the permission.  I don't see any reason to impede our ability to get work done, i.e., no reason to believe anyone else moving onwards and upwards would do differently.

Answer (score 1):

Reasonably strong root password. Different on each box. No remote root logins, and no passwords for logins, only keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh access via your certificates, can't you log in via ssh and change the `root` password via `passwd` or `sudo passwd` when you need to do something else that requires the password?

Comment: if you have root access you can change root password,
but users that have root access via certificates are supposed to not change the root password, for many reasons

Comment: Last time I tried it, passwd root prompted for the old root password even when already running as root, but then again no protection as root can edit /etc/shadow directly.

Answer (score 0):

We use the sudo only policy where I work, but root passwords are still kept. The root passwords are only available to a select few employees. We have a program called Password Manager Pro that stores all of our passwords, and can provide password audits as well. This allows us to go back and see what passwords have been accessed by which users. Thus, we're able to only change the passwords that actually need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

**SSH keys** have no real alternative.

For management of many `authorized_keys` files on many servers you have to implement your own solution, if you do not want the same file on every server. Either via an own tool, or with some configuration management solution like puppet, ansible or something like that.

Else a for loop in `bash` or some `clush` action will suffice.

**Anything besides SSH logins:**
For services you run that are login-based, use some sort of authentication with a central backend. *Keep in mind that noone will do any work if this backend is unavailable!*

Run the service clustered.
Don't do hacks with a super-duper-service backdoor account, to always have access in case something breaks (like admin access is broken due to a misconfiguration). No matter how much you monitor access or configuration changes affecting this account, this is 'just bad'(TM).

Instead of getting this backdoor right, you might as well just cluster the application, or at the very least have a spare system periodically mirroring the setup at hand if the main box dies, which then can be activated easily through routing changes in the network. If this sounds too complicated, your business is either too small and you can live with half a day to two days downtime. Or you really hate clusters due to lacking knowledge and are just saving on the wrong things.

**In general**: If you do use software unusable with some sort of Active Directory or LDAP integration you have to jump the shark and change passwords for these manually.

Also a dedicated password management database that can only be accessed by a very selected few directly, and is read-only to all the others, is very nice. Don't bother with excel files, these lack proper rights management. Working with version control on .csv files doesn't really cut it either after a certain treshold.